# Powershell DataTable one row counts 0

Tags: c#, powershell, datatable

I have a powershell script where i load a SQL Select into a `DataTable`.

When I set my query to only return 1 row and after do a `DataTable.Rows.Count` it prints 0 rows.

When i set my query to return 2 rows and after do a `DataTable.Rows.Count` it print 2 rows.

> I can see there is data in my `DataTable` with 0 rows, because I can do
>   a loop over my `DataTable`. So it still gets data it just prints 0

So why does my Count says 0 with 1 row?

If  I do a simple DataTable in C# and add 1 row. It counts 1.

**Powershell**

```
function ExecuteSqlQuery ($Server, $DB, $user, $pw, $SQLQuery) {

$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$Datatable.Clear()

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Server; Database = $DB; Integrated Security = False; User ID = $user; Password = $pw;Connection Timeout=0"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
$Command.CommandTimeout = 0
$Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
Write-Host $SQLQuery
Write-Host "Starting to read sql"

$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
Write-Host "Read of SQL success"
$Datatable.Load($Reader)
Write-Host "Datatable loaded with data"
$Connection.Close()

return $Datatable
}

Write-Output $query
$resultsDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery -Server $SQLServer -DB $SQLDBName -user $uid -pw $pwd -SQLQuery $query

Write-Output ("Meta Table contains: " + $resultsDataTable.Rows.Count + " rows")
```

**C#**

```
static void Main()
        {
            // Get the DataTable.
            DataTable table = GetTable();

            int s =table.Rows.Count;
        }

        static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int)); 
            table.Rows.Add(25);

            return table;
        }
```

Comment: When you are getting 1 row you also are getting the header row.

Comment: @jdweng But that does not resolve why i with 1 row is counting 0?

Comment: There isn't much info on the concerned table, query and output *data*. Anyways, if there is a `Count` column in your table, might explain what happens. Try: `@($resultsDataTable.Rows).Count`.

Comment: @iRon what more info do you need? It doesnt matter what the output is and how the query is. I get my desired results, I just dont understand why it counts as it does.

Comment: Why did you just delete the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333589/insert-string-to-datatable ???

Comment: @Enigmativity Because I just figured out that my split was working, it was a typo, and now it all works.

Comment: @SqlKindaGuy - You do have the option to vote to close your own question based on it being a typo. Also it's nice to let us know what the problem was. People do invest their time to help and it's good to get an outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the type of $resultsDataTable.

```
Write-Host $resultsDataTable.GetType()
```

I had similar issue and it seems that Powershell changes type of object to System.Data.DataRow when there is only one row returned.

Type change happens AFTER object is returned by function. Inside function "ExecuteSqlQuery" in Your example, it is still System.Data.DataTable.

Also, Your declaration of $resultsDataTable

```
$resultsDataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
```

is unnecessary as this newly created object is almost immediately overwritten in the next line of Your script when You are getting result back from ExecuteSqlQuery Function.